# Php thread, if page hits 30 second time out termination, auto restart thread

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I have a PHP thread running that is scraping data on the backend once I start it up, and can just leave it running.
I run into an issue though, where I'll find my php process stopped, because for some reason the entire scrape took longer than 30 seconds to load. I can obviously adjust that 30 seconds. But there may be some situations where if I"m scraping data, some source site is having issues, and likewise never fully loads, so that termination will naturally take effect.

Is there a process I can write in that auto restarts the php thread, instead of closing it if that happens? That would be my ideal, if possible.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Don't use php threads. This is difficult and buggy. Just run separated processes. And for communications you can use shared memory and semaphores or files with lock or database with transactions.

Comment: Can you provide some code to support your question? It's difficult to provide much guidance here without seeing what you currently have.